# Obtain method reference from java.lang.reflect.Method object

Tags: java, methods, reflection, reference

I have an object of type `java.lang.reflect.Method` and i need to set it to the fallowing variable `BiConsumer<_notaFiscalServicoGeraServicosMov, Double> metodoSetBC`.

Is it possible to obtain the reference from the `java.lang.reflect.Method` instance?

Comment: is it possible to obtain the reference from the java.lang.reflect.Method instance?

Comment: Do you want your `BiConsumer` to call the method represented by your `Method` object? What's the signature of that `Method`?

Comment: Its a setter 

`public void setValueBC(Double valueBC) {
        this.valueBC= valueBC;
    }`

Comment: And you effectively want to call `_notaFiscalServicoGeraServicosMovObject.setValueBC(doubleValue)`?

Comment: that method is an example. I have a list with methods all with the same signature, the user choose the method and assign a value to it.
I need to be able to call _notaFiscalServicoGeraServicosMovObject.setValueBC(doubleValue) or any other method that the user choose

Comment: "Assign a value to a method" doesn't make much sense. You can't replace a method in a class. If you mean that the user will dynamically call a setter, then maybe the answer below will help...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BiConsumer<_notaFiscalServicoGeraServicosMov, Double> consumer = (instance, param) -> {
    try {
        methodInstance.invoke(instance, new Object[] {param});
    } catch (LotsOfExceptionsHere e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
};
```

that should do it. There's no other way, really.

Comment: Yup, my bad. Edited the mistake.

Comment: i've found that answer, but netbeans says:
incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    unexpected return value